# How to clear the bottom of an image like clear left / right

Tags: css

Is there a way to clear the bottom of an image? I tried `margin-bottom: 100%`, and `padding-bottom: 100%`, but it is not working because I have more divs below which clears all.

I want to clear only the content of the image containing div.

#### HTML

```
<div class="contentpart">
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.s1waterbike.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/contact-feat1.jpg">
        <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-88" alt="contact-feat" src="http://www.s1waterbike.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/contact-feat1-300x200.jpg" height="200" width="300">
      </a>
    </p>
    the text....
</div>
<div class="contentpart">
   The text.....
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.contentpart img {
    float: left;
    clear: bottom;
}
```

Example of how the solution should look like

[image: example of how the solution should look like]

Comment: You need to post your html and css so we can see what's going wrong!

Comment: html and css..??whole code of urs?

Comment: http://www.s1waterbike.ro/indexnew.php/?page_id=10

Comment: i don`t know which part of the code to post, this is the page, you can inspect it,   
s1waterbike.ro/indexnew.php/?page_id=10

Comment: That's a dud link. Anyhow, sounds like you should just apply `overflow: hidden` to the image container.

Comment: This won't be helpful for other users, you need to post the bit of code you're having an issue with. If it's to do with the image, just psot the bit of code of the iamge and any surrounding content you're having the issue with, then the CSS specific to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your image, you can realize the layout by using the the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="contentpart">
      <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
      </a>
      Donec adipiscing, lorem non euismod venenatis...
</div>
```

and applying the following **CSS** rules:

```css
.contentpart {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    display: table;
}
.contentpart a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

You can see the demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/wknjA/

**How This Works**

You can use CSS tables to get the text to stay in a single column without wrapping it in a block element.

Apply `display: table` to the parent block and `display: table-cell` to the `a` tag.

You can have some control over white space by applying some padding to the `a` element.

Comment: thanks its working this way, but is not a solution for me, because the content will be edited by the user in the wp editor, and he don`t want to insert html codes like <p> ... </p>